# io.lines fails with "Bad address"

Tags: lua, io

The following line of code

```lua
for line in io.lines("/proc/meminfo") do
```

fails intermittently with the error message

> Bad address

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

I tried using `io.input("/proc/meminfo")` instead to read one line at a time but it produces the same error.

My OS is *Centos 7 kernel 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64*

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Centos 7 kernel 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64

Comment: may try to use `rb` mode?

Comment: The most reliable way for sure would be to write a simple Lua C module around [`<sys/sysinfo.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html).

Comment: What Lua distribution are you using?

Comment: Tried using the `"rb"` mode suggested above. Doesnt help.
Also tried reading the whole file and then iterating using `io.lines()` and that doesnt help either.
Seems like the problem is with the `io.lines()` iterator. Any other ideas to fix this?

Comment: you can just use `read` instead of `lines` iterator.